# Mutual dependency of two contracts

Tags: contract-design

I have the following code in `AuthorTokens.sol`:

```
    Files files;

    // ...

    function mintAuthor(address _owner) external {
        require(msg.sender == files, "System function");
        uint256 _id = _sellerToToken(_owner);
        balances[_id][_owner] = 10**digitsConstant;
        TransferSingle(msg.sender, 0, _owner, _id, 10**digitsConstant);
    }
```

This function should be called by the contract `Files.sol`, when a new "author" is added.

So, I have a mutual dependency of two contracts: `Files` and `AuthorTokens`. How to deal with this? Should I set both contracts to point to addresses of each other?

I could combine the two contracts into one but `Files` is ERC-20 and `AuthorTokens` is ERC-1155.

So, what to do?

Comment: It is clear the dependency of AuthorTokens on Files, but the other way around is not obvious. What is the dependency of Files on AuthorTokens. In the first case it should be possible to deploy Files contract, then call deploy AuthorTokens with Files' address as parameter.

Comment: The "other way" is that `Files` needs to call `mintAuthor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to move the contract initialization in a separate function

```
contract Files {
    ERC20 authorToken;
    function init(ERC20 token) public {
        require(address(authorToken) == address(0x0));
        authorToken = token;
    }
}


contract AuthorToken {
    Files files;
    function init(Files f) public {
        require(address(files) == address(0x0));
        files = f;
    }
}
```

The deployment will be slightly more complex because you have to make the calls to the init functions.